# Hello. I am using Godot 4.1 and I need a debug.keystore so I can export to android. I have no idea on how to make one

Tags: android, godot, android-keystore

I need it so u can export to android and I have no clue how. I did install android studio giraffe though. If you could give me a detailed step by step tutorial on how, that would be great

I tried just installing and screwing with the studio

And I did try waiting a video that did not help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into the godot docs help:

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/export/exporting_for_android.html

There you find a explanation how to generate debug.keystore and how to set it up in Godot.